# What is the -y flag in the `apt install` command?

Tags: linux, command-line, apt

I'm seeing the `-y` flag being used in `apt install -y` a lot today but when I do `man install` no `-y` flag is described.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15):

> Am I missing something?

When you invoke `apt install …` the command is `apt`, not `install`. `man install` will show you the manual for `install` which is a different command. The right place to start is `man apt`.

Some commands in a form `foo bar anything …` may have manuals available under `man foo-bar`. E.g. `man btrfs-subvolume` runs well, but `btfrs-subvolume` (as a command) doesn't exist, the syntax is `btrfs subvolume …`.

This is not the case with `apt` though; in my Debian there is no `man apt-install`. Yet `man apt` says `install (apt-get(8))` where it explains `apt install`, so now we know we should read

```
man 8 apt-get
```

And this is it, `-y` is explained *there*:

> `-y`, `--yes`, `--assume-yes`
>   Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs then `apt-get` will abort. […].

Answer (score 2):

-y means yes to everything.

If you're *absolutely* sure its something you want to do, or are scripting apt, its a good idea. In situations where you're pulling in additional packages as dependancies, for example, apt will check if you're sure, and in some cases you just want it to go ahead and not bother asking for permission.

Comment: The question is why the man pages do not display `-y`. Couldn't find it as well.

Comment: Oh. Thanks so much. It's a 'yes' to all then. :)